# flutter like_button on tap increment the value in the server

Tags: flutter, dart

I used the like button flutter package from https://pub.dev/packages/like_button
to include like button to my list view from api. I have a table which is contain the count of likes and I show them in every item. now I want to increment the count of likes after tap on like button, but the type of function is bool and I can pass item id as parameter. so please help to solve this issue

```
LikeButton(
                            onTap: onLikeButtonTapped,
                            size: 20,
                            circleColor:
                            CircleColor(start: Colors.pink, end: Colors.pinkAccent),
                            bubblesColor: BubblesColor(
                              dotPrimaryColor: Colors.red,
                              dotSecondaryColor: Colors.redAccent,
                            ),
                            likeBuilder: (bool isLiked) {
                              return Icon(
                                Icons.favorite,
                                color: isLiked ? Colors.pink : Colors.pink[300],
                                size: 20,
                              );
                            },
                            likeCount: news[index].count_like,
                            countBuilder: (int count, bool isLiked, String text) {
                              var color = isLiked ? Colors.grey[700] : Colors.grey[600];
                              Widget result;
                              if (count == 0) {
                                result = Text(
                                  "love",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: color),
                                );
                              } else
                                result = Text(
                                  text,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: color),
                                );
                              return result;
                            },
                          ),
```

and here is the predefined function which is provided by the package developer

```
Future<bool> onLikeButtonTapped(bool isLiked) async{

<!-- send your request here -->
<!-- final bool success= await sendRequest(); -->

<!-- if failed, you can do nothing -->
<!-- return success? !isLiked:isLiked; -->

  return !isLiked;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this could solve your problem, but I also had a similar situation to pass arguments through the function so I modified the function and somehow solved the issue. Hope it helps.

I used `ontap` like this:

```
onTap: (isLiked) {
                    return changedata(               
                    isLiked,
                      );
                  },
```

and then the function,

```
Future<bool> changedata(status) async {
    //your code
      return Future.value(!status);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you.